# How to compile expressions in Java

Tags: java, swt

I am writing an eclipse plugin with SWT. In my plugin I have requirement where i have to validate user entered expression(with 3 variables) and have to check if its a valid one. For example when user enters X || Y && Z, have to treat it as a valid expression. But if User enter something that cannot be compiled then have to report false. In C#, there is an option to compile the expression in memory and check for any errors or warnings. Is there an equivalent one in Java that can be used in SWT?

Comment: What kind of expressions you want to accept? Regular expressions containing &&, || and !?

Comment: yes. It needs to accept only expressions with max of 3 variables.(say X, Y, Z)